# jQuery - ''Uncaught TypeError" while executing "animate"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying out some jQuery examples given in [this](https://www.w3resource.com/jquery-exercises/part1/index.php#EDITOR) website. One such example was **scrolling back to the top of the page using "animate"**. Accordingly, I tried this in the console:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, "slow");
```

But I got an error such as this:

> VM54:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': duration must be non-negative or auto.
>       at :1:17
>   (anonymous) @ VM54:1

I even tried giving positive values for scrollTop. But this error occurs. What is the workaround for this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you are running the code on either doesn't include jQuery, or has a version of jQuery that doesn't support that code.  `$` is not universally jQuery, it can be any variable.

If you, for example, go to jquery.com and run that same code in the console, it will work.